# Primefaces galleria not displaying after adding captcha to the xhtml

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

On my page galleria was working fine before adding captcha to the code.

After adding captcha to the code galleria is not displaying on page.

I tried to keep both captcha on different form but still it is not working.

Captcha is working fine.

I've no idea what is problem with this.

```
<h:form id="frmTest">
  <center >
    <br/><br/>
    <table width="70%" border="0">      
        <tr>
           <td width="70%" align="center">
                 <p:panel >
                       <p:galleria value="#{LoginBean.imgList}" 
                                   var="image" effect="slide" 
                                   effectSpeed="1000"
                                   panelWidth="500" panelHeight="300" 
                                   frameWidth="100" frameHeight="70" 
                                   rendered="true">
                              <p:graphicImage value="../resources/images/{image}"/>
                         </p:galleria>
                 </p:panel>
            </td>
            <td width="30%">
                  <p:panel>
                          <p:commandButton id="btnShowCaptcha" 
                                           process="@form"
                                           onclick="captchaDlgWar.show()"
                                           value="Show Captcha"/>
                  </p:panel> 
            </td>
       </tr>
    </table>

  </center>

  <p:dialog widgetVar="captchaDlgWar" id="capchaDlgId"
             hideEffect="explode" showEffect="clip"
             modal="true" closable="true" resizable="false"
             header="Prove you are human..." width="360" height="190">

        <h:panelGrid columns="1">

               <p:captcha label="Captcha"
                               id="captchaId"
                               language="tr"
                               required="true"/>
               <p:commandButton id="btnContinue"
                                ajax="false"
                                value="Continue"
                                action="#{MyBean.onContinueAction}"/>

        </h:panelGrid>
  </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

MyBean

```
public String onContinueAction() {

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("captchaDlgWar.hide()");
    return "somePage.xhtml";

}
```

Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

try taking your `dialog` outside of your `form` and add another `form` inside your dialog

so you'll have one dialog with galeria inside and another dialog inside your `dialog` make sure you don't nest `forms`

```
<h:form.... <p:galleria...</h:form>
```

and

```
<p:dialog><h:form.... <p:captcha ...</h:form></p:dialog>
```

Also

I'd try to use `p:panelGrid` [Primefaces PanelGrid](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/panelGrid.jsf) instead of the table

Comment: Thanks Daniel I tried your solution but Still it's not Working. I also try to update the galleria on button click. After update on button click galleria appears. But it disappears when I click 'continue' button on dialog.

Comment: try to remove <h:panelgrid> or you can use <p:panelgrid> try this thing may this wil help you @AkshayRaut